# Advantages of netezza client tools over aginity

Tags: netezza, aginity

My team recently started working with Netezza. I'm responsible for loading data into the database in the most efficient manner. They want me to look into things such as automating the loading of data and more.

Right now I'm using Aginity as an interface to load data but I'm wondering if there are any advantages of using Netezza Client tools (with nzload and more) instead of Aginity whether it's for loading data or anything else. When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aginity is nice for exploration and code development.
IMHO you’ll need a proper (but lightweight) scripting language to do any kind of automated loading/extraction/manipulation of data.
Python, bash, powershell - doesn’t really matter.
Automation requires error handling and simple decision making combined with the ability to manipulate sql statements dynamically, and all scripting languages can do that.

Wether you call nzsql as a command line utility from that tool or uses an ODBC or JDBC capability in said scripting language is not of any consequence either.